# Javascript regex to match a block of code starting with a given pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm working with a javascript script and I need a quick way to match "JSDocs" using Regex. The pattern I'm trying to match is this.

```
# this is block1
/// text
/// text
/// text
/// text

# this is block2
/// text
/// text
/// text
/// text
```

so a block is defined by consecutive lines starting with "///" what I have so far is:

```
/(/^(\/{3}[\w\W]*)^(?!\/{3})/gm
```

so I'm starting at a line starting with `///` and then matching until a line doesn't start with `///` but for this to work I need to have two \n\n at the end of the input block and I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const result = text.match(/^\/{3}.*(?:\r?\n\/{3}.*)*/gm)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b22Zao/1/). Note the `g` and `m` flags. `g` will match all occurrences of the pattern in the string and `m` will make `^` match start of any line.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\/{3}` - three slashes
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n\/{3}.*)*` - zero or more sequences of a line ending (CRLF or LF) and the rest of the line.

See the JavaScipt demo:

```js
const text = '# this is block1\n/// text\n/// text\n/// text\n/// text\n\n# this is block2\n/// text\n/// text\n/// text\n/// text';
const result = text.match(/^\/{3}.*(?:\r?\n\/{3}.*)*/gm)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you so much that does the trick and is so much cleaner than what I did